# Recalling information form an array in list form

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to recall a list of employees from an array in Java. I can either choose to do them individually via their ID number or bring all employee info up at once. I know how to code everything else but I cannot find a clear tutorial on how to recall the data and project it onto the text box I have programmed into my GUI. I have the array already created in a different class but I need to get the information from that one and display it in the GUI. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

If you want more info just let me know.

[The image is a screenshot of the simple GUI I made.]

[image]

Comment: What code do you want? This is a small part of a large project. You will have to be more specific. As for what have I tried..that's the thing. I have done some research and look through a few books but nothing comes close to pointing me in the right direction. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but one simple way that may help you to understand this process is as follows:

Implement a store method that simply writes all data to a file in a format of your choice. XML is common, as is TSV or CSV. Some of those are very easy to use, as predefined classes exist to handle them partially or completely.

You will have to read the data you want to store from whereever you have it in your application, possibly in the text boxes directly.

Accordingly implement a restore method that reads the file and fills it back into your data structure and/or the text boxes.

Comment: Its not saved to a file, its saved to memory.

Comment: That should not make a difference, if I understand you correctly. You can store to physical files or memory streams alike.